# How do I handle data that already has headers?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that I'm trying to work with

My code is

```
DATA AlbumData;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/Data.txt' DLM=',';
    INPUT Movie $ Director $ Date ANYDTDTE10. Budget BoxOffice Genre $;
RUN;
```

My issue is the first line of the .txt file I'm importing has these same headings. How do I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `FIRSTOBS=2` option to the `INFILE` line.  This will tell the file pointer to start on line 2.

```
DATA AlbumData;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/Data.txt' DLM=',' FIRSTOBS=2;
    INPUT Movie $ Director $ Date ANYDTDTE10. Budget BoxOffice Genre $;
RUN;
```